# Struts what method is being called?

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, interceptor

How can I get the name of the method that will be called in the action from within an interceptor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the struts source I found the answer.

```
invocation.getProxy().getMethod();
```

Where invocation is the `ActionInvocation` passed to your interceptor.